# Why does cout.setf(ios::fixed) change my floats to hexadecimal?

Tags: c++, cout

I experienced this weird issue recently having to do with cout.setf(ios::fixed). Took me quite a while to track down the cause and  thought I'd ask here to learn more.

The issue is this - all floating point numbers were printed as hexadecimal numbers when using cout.setf(ios::fixed). Why does this happen? The documentation of ios::base doesn't seem to imply that this will happen (at least to me). I am using g++ 5.3.0 and pasted below is a minimal example and the output.

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <complex>

   using namespace std;

   int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
   {
    complex<double> I(0.0, 1.0);
    double pi = M_PI;

    cout.setf(ios::scientific);
    cout<<" I is "<<I<<endl;
    cout<<" Exp(I Pi) "<<exp(I*pi)<<endl;
    cout<<" Cos(Pi) "<<cos(pi)<<endl<<endl;

    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout<<" I is "<<I<<endl;
    cout<<" Exp(I Pi) "<<exp(I*pi)<<endl;
    cout<<" Cos(Pi) "<<cos(pi)<<endl<<endl;

    return 0;
   }
```

Output

```
 I is (0.000000e+00,1.000000e+00)
 Exp(I Pi) (-1.000000e+00,1.224647e-16)
 Cos(Pi) -1.000000e+00

 I is (0x0p+0,0x1p+0)
 Exp(I Pi) (-0x1p+0,0x1.1a62633145c07p-53)
 Cos(Pi) -0x1p+0
```

[<kbd>See the live sample here</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0d1b8949ce9e4b0)

Note that the issue goes away when I change

```
 cout.setf(ios::fixed);
```

to

```
 cout.setf(ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);
```

Answer (score 7):

**Because you told it to.**

From [`setf` documentation on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf):

> **scientific** - generate floating point types using scientific notation, or hex notation if combined with fixed: see `std::scientific`
>   **fixed** - generate floating point types using fixed notation, or hex notation if combined with scientific: see `std::fixed`

So, when setting `std::fixed`, you need to unset `std::scientific` (which is what your unmasking of `std::floatfield` does, because `std::floatfield` is `std::scientific|std::fixed|(std::scientific|std::fixed)|0`) to avoid the hex notation.

Comment: lightning strikes again :D,  +1 though:)

Comment: Thanks! Embarrassing mistake.